# Shell scripting sub string extraction

Tags: shell, substring

I have a set of file names following some pattern. I need to insert a date into the filename string. Now, I also have some files following a slightly different pattern. I would like to know how can a single string match both the requirements.

eg. filenames are like:

```
abcTrade_proj.dat 
abcPosition_proj.dat 
abcAccount_proj.dat
```

I'm using below string to construnct the filename like `abcTrade_yyyymmdd_proj.dat`

```
${filename%_*}_${DATE}_${filename#*_}
```

Now, apart from the above file patterns, I have the pattern:

```
abc_pqr_Account_proj.dat 
abc_pqr_Trade_proj.dat
```

All i need to do is cut the string till the last `_`, insert the date and append the string that is there after `_`, for both the type of file patterns.

Is there any solution for both situations?

Comment: what you mean by "till last ''" ?

Comment: it is like, i need to split the string based upon last _. so that irrespective of no.of unserscores in the first part of the filename, i can always split based upon the last uderscore.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you could use `sed` to construct the new name as follows:

```
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
echo "abcTrade_pqr_proj.dat" | sed "s/^\(.*\)_\([^_]*\)/\1_${DATE}_\2/g"
```

which results in:

```
abcTrade_pqr_20140101_proj.dat
```

Comment: May I suggest `export DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)` for the date of current day, at same format?

Comment: THanks Eric. sed can be used to cut the strings. I shall test and let you know.